# Route all traffic from laptop to home network. Recommended Method?

Tags: networking, openvpn

I travel and use open wifi networks a lot. Given the nature of my work I want to route all my traffic thru my home network. My home office is well equipped to handle such a connection.

Basically I need to route all traffic (all ports, udp and tcp) over SSL to my home network so its like im sitting on the same subnet. My home router is on a static IP and supports IPSec and SSL VPN as an endpoint.

Right now i'm using SSH and tunneling ports one by one but its far from elegant and annoying to setup even with batch files. I have not experimented with VPN. Does this sound possible and worth looking into with OpenVPN as the client on my laptop connecting to my router as the VPN endpoint? I also have a 2008 R2 server if I need a different endpoint but prefer to use my router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds perfectly doable, router's built-in mobile IPSec or Windows 2008 (L2TP over IPSec).  Your call.  Just make sure that your router's VPN software/client creates a default route through the tunnel interface (or in Windows, "use default gateway on remote network" is checked off on your VPN connection under Advanced TCP/IP settings).

Comment: You make it sound as though what I need is built into windows on the client side. Is there a need for a VPN client or is all I need built into windows 7? Is that that setting just so that all traffic is routed thru my remote/home gateway?

Comment: Windows (XP/7) has built-in support for PPTP, L2TP over IPSec, etc. Mobile or "Road Warrior" IPSec VPN for Ciscos, Netgear, etc. will usually require client software, but once it's setup, it's trivial to use.  There's a couple of free ones, ShrewSoft comes to mind as a solid one and your router may actually have one embedded/available to download.  As for routes, yes, by default, Windows should create a default route through the VPN interface, but most will have an option to do so (without it, it's called split tunnelling).

Comment: Perfect thanks, going to do some reading and tinkering.

Answer (score 1):

Openvpn will do this as well.  You'll want your default route to be the VPN server.  Try this link.

http://www.structuretoobig.com/post/2008/01/14/Road-Warrior-Setup-OpenVPN.aspx